# How to get Server Path in Core class library project into the static method

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-2.2

I am using .Net Core 2.2 class library project and I want Server root path in my one of the static method. I know that using IHostingEnvironment I can get server path using DI and I can not use DI for static method.

```
public class MyProcessor
{
    public static string XXXXXX()
    { 
        //Need Server root path here
    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why is your method static? Is that really necessary?

Comment: Short answer: You can't.  Suggestion: Make the class/method instance instead of static so dependencies can be injected. Can you explain why the method needs to be static?

Comment: DI doesn't play nice with statics and vice-versa. You'll pretty much choose one approach or the other, not mix and match. An object with a singleton lifetime in DI is usually a good replacement for whatever you think needs to be static.

Comment: @RobertPerry I am upgrading application from MVC to Core and my one of class library project have this code

Comment: Refactor time then I guess :-)